# why scala.util.Try has an instance in cats but not in scalaz?

Tags: scala, try-catch, functor, scalaz

typelevel's cats(version 0.9.0) has a Functor instance for Try

```
object catsTry {
  import cats.Functor
  import cats.instances.try_._
  import scala.util.Try
  val f = implicitly[Functor[Try]] //compile
}
```

while there is no Functor instance for Try in scalaz(version 7.3.0-M12).

```
object scalazTry {
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._
  import scala.util.Try
  val f = implicitly[Functor[Try]] // won't compile
}
```

I wonder any reason why scalaz doesn't provide an Functor instance for Try?

P.S. thanks Ren's comments. I tried the case on https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6284

```
@ Success(1) map { ((i:Int)=>numberOrDefault(i)) compose divideByZero } 
res3: Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)

@ Success(1) map divideByZero map ((i:Int)=>numberOrDefault(i)) 
res4: Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

it looks like that the law hold. am I missing something?

Comment: Discussion https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/1059

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because Try breaks function composition laws. There is an implementation under scalaz-outlaws (Instances for typeclasses that break the laws of various typeclasses), here - https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/outlaws/std/Try.scala.

See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6284

Comment: Looks like it. Its a matter of perspective: With the Scalaz approach, if you have a functor, you can reason about its behaviour safely, because you know it satisfies the functor laws. eg. you can compose things together and know the expected outcome.

With the Cats approach, you can use the Try in places that need a functor typeclass, but you need to be more careful - it may cause issues that you need to understand the implementation to know about.